# Montando um 'quadro' em html a partir de um array em php

Tags: php, html, sql

As tabelas:

- Ciencias  (ex: Matemática, Biologia, Química).
- Areas  (ex: Algebra I, Bioquímica, Botânica, Ligações Químicas).
- Exercícios  (ex:Água, Algas, Briófitas, Progressões, Ligações Químicas).

Para usar como neste exemplo [ Quadro 01 ] no html:

> [ *Quadro 01* ]
>
> **Matemática**
>   - Algebra I(1)
>   **Biologia**
>   - Bioquímica(1)
>   - Botânica(2)
>   **Química**
>    - Ligações Químicas(1)

**Obs:Na tabela [exercícios] existe exercícios de todas as áreas**, que para serem identificadas em relação as tabelas ciencias e areas, criei colunas como: exercicioArea, exercicioCiencia.

A 'lógica' que pensei é de usar o inner join que encontrei em: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp para juntar as tabelas ficando assim:

> SELECT *
>   ciencias.ciencia as cienciaNome,
>   areas.area as materiaNome,
>   exercicios.exercicio as exercicioNome
>   FROM ciencias
>       INNER JOIN areas
>       ON areas.areaCiencia=ciencia.id
>       INNER JOIN exercicios
>       ON exercicios.exercicioArea = areas.id
>   ORDER BY cienciaNome ASC

Para saber a quantidade de exercícios encontrei essa maneira em: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_count.asp
**echo count();**
Que neste caso iria contar o número de elementos no array.

```
            Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [cienciaNome] => Biologia
                        [materiaNome] => Bioquímica
                        [exercicioNome] => Água
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [cienciaNome] => Biologia
                        [materiaNome] => Botânica
                        [exercicioNome] => Algas
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [cienciaNome] => Biologia
                        [materiaNome] => Botânica
                        [exercicioNome] => Briófitas
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [cienciaNome] => Matemática
                        [materiaNome] => Algebra I
                        [exercicioNome] => Conceito Progressões
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [cienciaNome] => Química
                        [materiaNome] => Ligações Químicas
                        [exercicioNome] => Conceito Ligações Químicas
                    )

            )
            Contagem array = 5
```

Porém não estou conseguindo entender como montar o  [ Quadro 01 ] a partir do array, como por exemplo existe 3 Biologia no array e no Quadro 01 só precisou colocar 1 vez.

> [ *Quadro 01* ]
>
> **Matemática**
>   - Algebra I(1)
>   **Biologia**
>   - Bioquímica(1)
>   - Botânica(2)
>   **Química**
>    - Ligações Químicas(1)

Comment: Você só precisa montar o quadro 01 a partir do array mencionado ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o problema for montar o quadro 01, segue a solução:

```
    <?php 
         //Criando o array mencionado
         $array_original = array(
                0 => array(
                        'cienciaNome' => 'Biologia',
                        'materiaNome' => 'Bioquímica',
                        'exercicioNome' => 'Água'
                    ),
                1 => array(
                        'cienciaNome' => 'Biologia',
                        'materiaNome' => 'Botânica',
                        'exercicioNome' => 'Algas'
                    ),
                2 => array(
                        'cienciaNome' => 'Biologia',
                        'materiaNome' => 'Botânica',
                        'exercicioNome' => 'Briófitas'
                    ),
                3 => array(
                        'cienciaNome' => 'Matemática',
                        'materiaNome' => 'Algebra I',
                        'exercicioNome' => 'Conceito Progressões'
                    ),
               4 => array(
                        'cienciaNome' => 'Química',
                        'materiaNome' => 'Ligações Químicas',
                        'exercicioNome' => 'Conceito Ligações Químicas'
                    )
    );

    //preparando um array inicial para exibição
    $array_tratado = array();
    foreach ($array_original as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            if ($k == 'cienciaNome') {
                $cienciaNome = $v;
            }else if($k == 'materiaNome'){
                $materiaNome = $v;
            }elseif ($k == 'exercicioNome') {
                $array_tratado[$cienciaNome][] = $materiaNome;
                $materiaNome = '';
                $cienciaNome = '';
            }
        }
    }

    //preparando um array final para exibição
    $array_final = array();
    foreach ($array_tratado as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
          //Nessa linha eu populo o array multidimensional com as chaves correspondentes;
          //O valor que nesse caso é o nome da matéria; 
          //É a mesma lógica do array de cima.
          $array_final[$key][$v][] = $v;
        }
    }

    // exibindo o array
    echo '[ Quadro 01 ]';
    foreach ($array_final as $key => $value) {
        echo "<ul><strong>$key</strong> (" . count($value) . ')';
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            echo "<li>$k (" . count($v) . ')</li> ';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ola @user31050 fico feliz por ter ajudado. A chave de um array nunca se repete no mesmo nível. Foi isso que aconteceu. Caso queira agrupar também as matérias basta transforma-las em array também.

Comment: Poste para ajudarmos.

Comment: Pronto @user31050 Agora ele exibe a quantidade na frente.

Comment: Na verdade eu editei meu código. Pode testar.

Comment: Ok, valeu @Ricardo Mota ajudou bastante se puder comentar essa linha do código também fico grato $array_final[$key][$v][] = $v;

Comment: Comentei @user31050 ;)